# Finding an eigenvector for a specific eigenvalue of a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic, eigenvalues

The relevant matrix is
$$M=\left( \begin{matrix} p^3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}p^8 & p^1-ip^2 & p^4-ip^5 \\
p^1 +i p^2 & -p^3 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}p^8 & p^6-ip^7\\
p^4+i p^5 & p^6+i p^7 & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}p^8\end{matrix} \right)$$

```
{{p3 + p8/Sqrt[3], p1 - I p2, 
  p4 - I p5}, {p1 + I p2, -p3 + p8/Sqrt[3], p6 - I p7}, {p4 + I p5, 
  p6 + I p7, -((2 p8)/Sqrt[3])}}
```

using the `Eigenvectors[]` function returns only zero and an error "unable to find all eigenvectors". I have separately found the eigenvalues $\mu_i$ by solving the cubic characteristic polynomial. This was surely half of the difficulty of the problem. To find the corresponding eigenvector should simply be a problem of Gaussian elimination on $(M-\mu_1I)\vec{v}=0$

My question is, what is the most streamlined way to now find the eigenvector corresponding to a specific e-val, say $\mu_1$? (I haven't included the explicit expression for $\mu_i$ as they are lengthy and it seems to me the problem can be equally solved while keeping it abstract.)

Comment: You could just use `NullSpace[]` on $\mathbf M-\mu_1\mathbf I$... in any event, "unable to find all eigenvectors" is usually a sign that you should be inspecting the result of `JordanDecomposition[]`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this function. Nonetheless NullSpace gives me the empty set in my case.

Comment: "`NullSpace` gives me the empty set in my case" - then, did you check that your expression for the eigenvalue is correct? (That is, what happens if you plug it into `CharacteristicPolynomial[M, x]`?)

Comment: Well I had kept $\mu_1$ in abstract form initially. It seemed to me (perhaps erroneously) that one should find a solution nonetheless from simple (at the conceptual level) Guassian elimination. I have now put in the explicit form  of $\mu_1$ and do get an answer. thanks

Comment: "Well I had kept $\mu_1$ in abstract form initially." - indeed, that wouldn't work, since `NullSpace[]` is not intended to find a (set of) null vector(s) unless the input matrix is manifestly rank-deficient.

Comment: Is there a method that would give me an answer keeping $\mu_1$ abstract? it's explicit form is not pretty..

Comment: I get a (lengthy) output on `Eigenvalues[mat]` for your matrix in Mathematica 12.1 (and an even longer one for the `EigenVectors`

Comment: yes the expressions can be very lengthy. I can however improve their complexity because there are some combinations that will often appear and I can rewrite them compactly. If I could find a way to get the eigenvectors in terms of the abstract $\mu_1$ variable it would go a long way in helping me then reguise into a more simple form..

Comment: @J.M... Actually that message is indicative of a bug. There are three (generically) distinct eigenvalues, hence there should be three eigenvectors. Also the fact that `NullSpace` came up empty more or less explains (to me, at least) where the bug is. Or was-- I have not yet checked in version 12.1 as this machine only has 11.3

Comment: I'm working in 11.3 myself. I've tried Solve[ $(M_{ij} - \mu \delta_{ij}) v_j $ == 0, {v1,v2,v3} ] but it also only returned the zero vector

Comment: @Daniel, I was running something else at the time I made my first comment, so I didn't try evaluating it then. Now, checking in 11.2, I see that `Eigenvectors[]` and `Eigensystem[]` indeed fail, yet `JordanDecomposition[]` works fine (and exhibits no Jordan blocks).

Comment: @Rudyard, as I already mentioned, use `JordanDecomposition[]` for now; since the second matrix returned is diagonal, the result of that is effectively an eigendecomposition.

Comment: @J.M. I hadn't initially appreciated the extent of your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: This does appear to have been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On *Mathematica* 12.1 I can get the `Eigenvectors` and `Eigenvalues`. I noticed each eigenvalue was 1/3 times some `Root` expression so I created some replacement rules to express the eigenvectors in terms of the $\mu_i$

```
m = {{p3 + p8/Sqrt[3], p1 - I p2, 
    p4 - I p5}, {p1 + I p2, -p3 + p8/Sqrt[3], p6 - I p7}, {p4 + I p5, 
    p6 + I p7, -((2 p8)/Sqrt[3])}};
eval = Eigenvalues[m];
rules = {eval[[1, 2]] :> 3 μ1, eval[[2, 2]] :> 3 μ2, 
   eval[[3, 2]] :> 3 μ3};
evec = Eigenvectors[m];
FullSimplify[evec /. rules]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{(\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) \left(3 \text{$\mu $1}+2 \sqrt{3} \text{p8}\right)+3
   (\text{p4}-i \text{p5}) (\text{p6}+i \text{p7})}{3 (\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) (\text{p4}+i
   \text{p5})-(\text{p6}+i \text{p7}) \left(-3 \text{$\mu $1}+3 \text{p3}+\sqrt{3}
   \text{p8}\right)} & \frac{3 \text{$\mu $1}^2-3 \text{$\mu $1} \text{p3}-2 \sqrt{3}
   \text{p3} \text{p8}-3 \text{p4}^2-3 \text{p5}^2-2 \text{p8}^2+\sqrt{3} \text{$\mu $1}
   \text{p8}}{3 (\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) (\text{p4}+i \text{p5})-(\text{p6}+i \text{p7})
   \left(-3 \text{$\mu $1}+3 \text{p3}+\sqrt{3} \text{p8}\right)} & 1 \\
 \frac{(\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) \left(3 \text{$\mu $2}+2 \sqrt{3} \text{p8}\right)+3
   (\text{p4}-i \text{p5}) (\text{p6}+i \text{p7})}{3 (\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) (\text{p4}+i
   \text{p5})-(\text{p6}+i \text{p7}) \left(-3 \text{$\mu $2}+3 \text{p3}+\sqrt{3}
   \text{p8}\right)} & \frac{3 \text{$\mu $2}^2-3 \text{$\mu $2} \text{p3}-2 \sqrt{3}
   \text{p3} \text{p8}-3 \text{p4}^2-3 \text{p5}^2-2 \text{p8}^2+\sqrt{3} \text{$\mu $2}
   \text{p8}}{3 (\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) (\text{p4}+i \text{p5})-(\text{p6}+i \text{p7})
   \left(-3 \text{$\mu $2}+3 \text{p3}+\sqrt{3} \text{p8}\right)} & 1 \\
 \frac{(\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) \left(3 \text{$\mu $3}+2 \sqrt{3} \text{p8}\right)+3
   (\text{p4}-i \text{p5}) (\text{p6}+i \text{p7})}{3 (\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) (\text{p4}+i
   \text{p5})-(\text{p6}+i \text{p7}) \left(-3 \text{$\mu $3}+3 \text{p3}+\sqrt{3}
   \text{p8}\right)} & \frac{3 \text{$\mu $3}^2-3 \text{$\mu $3} \text{p3}-2 \sqrt{3}
   \text{p3} \text{p8}-3 \text{p4}^2-3 \text{p5}^2-2 \text{p8}^2+\sqrt{3} \text{$\mu $3}
   \text{p8}}{3 (\text{p1}-i \text{p2}) (\text{p4}+i \text{p5})-(\text{p6}+i \text{p7})
   \left(-3 \text{$\mu $3}+3 \text{p3}+\sqrt{3} \text{p8}\right)} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Copy-able result below:

```
{{(3 (p4 - I p5) (p6 + I p7) + (p1 - I p2) (2 Sqrt[3] p8 + 
      3 μ1))/(
  3 (p1 - I p2) (p4 + I p5) - (p6 + I p7) (3 p3 + Sqrt[3] p8 - 
      3 μ1)), (-3 p4^2 - 3 p5^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] p3 p8 - 2 p8^2 - 
   3 p3 μ1 + Sqrt[3] p8 μ1 + 3 μ1^2)/(
  3 (p1 - I p2) (p4 + I p5) - (p6 + I p7) (3 p3 + Sqrt[3] p8 - 
      3 μ1)), 1}, {(
  3 (p4 - I p5) (p6 + I p7) + (p1 - I p2) (2 Sqrt[3] p8 + 3 μ2))/(
  3 (p1 - I p2) (p4 + I p5) - (p6 + I p7) (3 p3 + Sqrt[3] p8 - 
      3 μ2)), (-3 p4^2 - 3 p5^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] p3 p8 - 2 p8^2 - 
   3 p3 μ2 + Sqrt[3] p8 μ2 + 3 μ2^2)/(
  3 (p1 - I p2) (p4 + I p5) - (p6 + I p7) (3 p3 + Sqrt[3] p8 - 
      3 μ2)), 1}, {(
  3 (p4 - I p5) (p6 + I p7) + (p1 - I p2) (2 Sqrt[3] p8 + 3 μ3))/(
  3 (p1 - I p2) (p4 + I p5) - (p6 + I p7) (3 p3 + Sqrt[3] p8 - 
      3 μ3)), (-3 p4^2 - 3 p5^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] p3 p8 - 2 p8^2 - 
   3 p3 μ3 + Sqrt[3] p8 μ3 + 3 μ3^2)/(
  3 (p1 - I p2) (p4 + I p5) - (p6 + I p7) (3 p3 + Sqrt[3] p8 - 
      3 μ3)), 1}}
```

Edit: the eigenvalues look like this:

```
{1/3 Root[-27 p3 p4^2 - 27 p3 p5^2 - 54 p1 p4 p6 - 54 p2 p5 p6 + 
     27 p3 p6^2 + 54 p2 p4 p7 - 54 p1 p5 p7 + 27 p3 p7^2 - 
     18 Sqrt[3] p1^2 p8 - 18 Sqrt[3] p2^2 p8 - 18 Sqrt[3] p3^2 p8 + 
     9 Sqrt[3] p4^2 p8 + 9 Sqrt[3] p5^2 p8 + 9 Sqrt[3] p6^2 p8 + 
     9 Sqrt[3] p7^2 p8 + 
     6 Sqrt[3]
       p8^3 + (-9 p1^2 - 9 p2^2 - 9 p3^2 - 9 p4^2 - 9 p5^2 - 9 p6^2 - 
        9 p7^2 - 9 p8^2) #1 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 1/3 Root[-27 p3 p4^2 - 27 p3 p5^2 - 54 p1 p4 p6 - 54 p2 p5 p6 + 
     27 p3 p6^2 + 54 p2 p4 p7 - 54 p1 p5 p7 + 27 p3 p7^2 - 
     18 Sqrt[3] p1^2 p8 - 18 Sqrt[3] p2^2 p8 - 18 Sqrt[3] p3^2 p8 + 
     9 Sqrt[3] p4^2 p8 + 9 Sqrt[3] p5^2 p8 + 9 Sqrt[3] p6^2 p8 + 
     9 Sqrt[3] p7^2 p8 + 
     6 Sqrt[3]
       p8^3 + (-9 p1^2 - 9 p2^2 - 9 p3^2 - 9 p4^2 - 9 p5^2 - 9 p6^2 - 
        9 p7^2 - 9 p8^2) #1 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 1/3 Root[-27 p3 p4^2 - 27 p3 p5^2 - 54 p1 p4 p6 - 54 p2 p5 p6 + 
     27 p3 p6^2 + 54 p2 p4 p7 - 54 p1 p5 p7 + 27 p3 p7^2 - 
     18 Sqrt[3] p1^2 p8 - 18 Sqrt[3] p2^2 p8 - 18 Sqrt[3] p3^2 p8 + 
     9 Sqrt[3] p4^2 p8 + 9 Sqrt[3] p5^2 p8 + 9 Sqrt[3] p6^2 p8 + 
     9 Sqrt[3] p7^2 p8 + 
     6 Sqrt[3]
       p8^3 + (-9 p1^2 - 9 p2^2 - 9 p3^2 - 9 p4^2 - 9 p5^2 - 9 p6^2 - 
        9 p7^2 - 9 p8^2) #1 + #1^3 &, 3]}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you post the eigenvalues too please so I know which e-vector corresponds to which $\mu$?